# What actually is the assignment symbol in python?

Tags: python, operators, language-theory

Most sources online call = (and +=, -=, etc...) an assignment operator (for python). This makes sense in most languages, however, not in python. An operator takes one or more operands, returns a value, and forms an expression. However, in python, assignment is not an expression, and assignment does not yield a value. Therefore, = cannot be an operator.

So what exactly is it? In a statement like x = 0, x is an identifier, 0 is a numeric literal, but I don't know what to call "=".

Comment: Where are you getting your definition of operator?  There are other operators in python (`del` for example) that also do not meet your criteria.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh The wording of the definition is my own but comes from my understanding of programming language theory, which comes from my attempts at implementing parsers. As far as I can tell, official python documentation supports this definition, see my answer below. Assignment is a statement, not an expression. likewise, del is a statement, not an operator.

Comment: @Jainil Patel An expression is a combination of identifiers, literals, and operators that yields another value. In python, assignment does not yield another value but only produces a side effect (assignment). e.g. x = y = 1 is illegal syntax because y = 1 does not yield a value to assign to x.

Comment: `x = y = 1` is legal syntax (Though you're right that assignment doesn't produce a value).

Comment: @Patrick Haugh Yes, sorry that was a bad example. That syntax is covered by the expression statement production rule (the * at the end covers that syntax): expr_stmt: testlist_star_expr (annassign | augassign (yield_expr|testlist) | ('=' (yield_expr|testlist_star_expr))*)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the correct answer in the official python documentation. = and friends are considered delimiters. source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

python docs reference for expressions does not define = as an operator nor as forming an expression. source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

It does, however, define assignment statements with their own production rule with = explicitly included in the rule. source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

So the final answer is that it is "delimiter" according to official sources.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment symbol `=` behaves like a statement, not as an operator.  It supports chaining as part of the syntax but cannot be used as an operation (e.g. `a = b = 0` but not `if a = b:`).

It is similar to the `in` part of a `for ... in ...:` statement. That `in` is part of the statement syntax, it is not the actual `in` operator.